# $GL_n(R)$ is open set in $M_n(R)$

Tags: general-topology, matrices

Show that set of all invertible $n\times n$ matrices with real entries (denoted by $GL_n(R)$) is open set in $M_n(R)$.

My attempt: by open set I think it means neighborhood of every point in set is contained in set, but this definition doesn't seem to help solve this question. Any other approach?

Comment: Have you tried anything further than just writing down the definition of open sets?

Comment: i think op needs some help to apply this definition.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If  you  can  show  that  its  complement  is  a  closed  set  the  also  you  prove  that  $$GL_{n}(\mathbb R)$$  is  open.

Now  see  that  the   complement  of  $GL_{n}(\mathbb R)$ is  the  set  of  all  matrices  that  have  determinant  $0$. And  $$det : M_{n}(\mathbb R)\rightarrow \mathbb R$$  is  a  continuous  function.

For  continuous  functions, pre-image  of a  closed  set  is  closed  and  $\{0\}$  is  a  closed  set  in  $\mathbb R$.

So  the  pre-image  of  this  singleton  closed  set  under  the  determinant  map, i.e., the  set  of  all  non-invertible  matrices, i.e., the  complement  of the  set  $GL_{n}(\mathbb R)$  is  a  closed  set.

Hence  $GL_{n}(\mathbb R)$  is open in $M_{n}(\mathbb R)$.

Comment: Why did you use the complement? The preimage of an open set by a continuous function is open as well, and $\mathbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. Exactly the same proof without needing to consider the complement.